# Ruby - adding values and saving them to continue the next call on a method

Tags: ruby

I have a problem where when I call on my createGadget where when price is = 650 and other price is $32 it does not add up.  when I call on it price gets reset and price is now 32. what do you do to save the previous value (which is 650) and add up the new value (which is 32)?

```
def money_made(cash)
    temp = 0
    temp = cash + temp 
    return temp
end 

def createGadget(make, model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    a = Gadget.new( make, model, price, height, width, weight)
        @@reveune_earned += money_made(a.price) 
        print money_made(a.price)
        print "\n"

        @@no_of_products +=1 
        puts @@no_of_products 
    return a 
end
```

Edit:

Here's the tester I forgot to add:

```
c = AppleStore.new()
macbook= c.createGadget( :Apple, :Macbook, 650,  13, 10, 3, :pounds)
puts "here is your macbook"
puts macbook 
d = AppleStore.new()
miniIpod = c.createGadget( :Apple, :MinIPod, 32,  13, 10, 3, :pounds)
```

The result I want:

```
price is 683 dollars
```

Results that I am getting:

```
650 #price 
1  #counter 
here is your macbook
#<Gadget:0x23f1ed0>
32# now price is reset to 49 
2 #counter
```

Comment: '@@no_of_products =0'
'@@reveune_earned = 0'

Comment: What the mean of `does not add up`? Have some errors or the result is not you want? Can you post the command and the result?

Comment: You print out `money_made(a.price)`, which value is apparently exactly equal to it’s argument. The aggregator `@@reveune_earned` should collect the value correctly. Simply try to `puts @@reveune_earned`.

Answer (score 0):

Using class variables to control state is a very bad idea. Printing stuff as side-effect from inside methods can be useful as a debugging technique, but you shouldn't leave those `print` calls in there. Also, I'm a little confused: why the class is called `AppleStore` if you need to pass the maker as an argument? What's the purpose of `weight_scale` if it's ignored inside the method? And what should the `money_made` method do?

If I may so, I'd refactor that code to something like this:

```rb
class Store
  def initialize(maker)
    @maker = maker
    @gadgets = []
  end

  def create_gadget(model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    gadget = Gadget.new(@make, model, price, height, width, weight, weight_scale)
    @gadgets << gadget
    gadget
  end

  def revenue
    @gadgets.reduce(0) { |total, gadget| total + gadget.price }
  end

  def number_of_gadgets
    @gadgets.count
  end
end

store = Store.new(:Apple)
macbook= store.create_gadget(:Macbook, 650,  13, 10, 3, :pounds)
puts "here is your macbook"
puts macbook
mini_ipod = store.create_gadget(:MinIPod, 32,  13, 10, 3, :pounds)
store.revenue
# => 682

store.number_of_gadgets
#=> 2
```